# 16.04 Display Issue

Tags: 16.04, display, menu

Upgrade to 16.04 desktop is quite a chore. After reading quite a bit here, I learned that VGA monitors may be a problem on AMD A10 systems, and found that if I switched to the DVI input, I gained a display again! YAY! Unfortunately, no desktop icons, panel, or menus appear.

To assure as much compatabilty, I ran the upgrade again, but nothing changed. Diddling with Desktop settings, and Menu settings did nothing. I can right click and see the application menu, but creating a launcher does not add an icon to the desktop.

I went to Software Updater and ran it again, it found ~1meg worth of stuff and installed it. I rebooted and have the same problem.

Incidently, switching back to the VGA input remains a black screen.

At this point all I can say is..."Give me back 14.04!"

What am I missing?

TIA,
-fab